# Why MultinomialNB outputs 0.5 when there is only one feature?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

A naive Bayesian classification problem

Code

```python
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]], dtype=int)
Y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.partial_fit(X, Y, [0, 1])
print clf.predict_proba(X)
```

Output

```python
[[ 0.5  0.5]
 [ 0.5  0.5]
 [ 0.5  0.5]
 [ 0.5  0.5]
 [ 0.5  0.5]
 [ 0.5  0.5]]
```

MultinomialNB seems to calculate only the priori probability

How to solve this problem?

For example, the expected output

```python
[[ 0.1  0.9]
 [ 0.1  0.9]
 [ 0.1  0.9]
 [ 0.9  0.1]
 [ 0.9  0.1]
 [ 0.9  0.1]]
```

Comment: Yes. Thats expected of Naive bayes as [documented here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html#multinomial-naive-bayes). Maybe try another model or provide more data and features